# Facebook Messenger API "request body undefined"

Tags: facebook

After following all the steps as per the standard documentation, I am getting `req.body` undefined in my webhook:

```
app.post('/webhook/', function(req, res) {  
    console.log("message received " + req.body);
    if(!req.body){
        console.log("no request body found");
        res.sendStatus(200);
        return;
    }

    messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
        sender = event.sender.id;
        console.log("sender " + event.sender + ", message " + event.message.text);
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            text = event.message.text;
            // Handle a text message from this sender
            sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: "+ text.substring(0, 200));
        }
    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

**Edit**

Do I need to Approve the Bot before I can test? also my Facebook Page is Live

Comment: Webhooks do not send a “normal” POST request (like f.e. an HTML form would), they send JSON data directly with the appropriate content type. Most frameworks/languages don’t populate the usual request data structures automatically in that case (like PHP with its $_POST superglobal), but instead you have to read the _raw_ data yourself. If that is the case for your language/framework (which you did not even mention, btw.), you’ll have to research.

Comment: @CBroe I am using Parse Cloud Code deployed on Heroku

Comment: where can i find the same code in C#.Net ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Latest versions of Express (4.x) has unbundled the middleware from the core framework. If you need body parser, you need to install it separately

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

and then do this in your code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Thanks @Giovanne Dias it was my mistake, i didn't realise that body parser was not initialized

Comment: Thank I search that since 3 hours :)